# Force bracket notation when compiling from CoffeeScript to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

As stated in the title: Is there a way to force bracket notation in JavaScript when compiling classes from CoffeeScript?

A simple example would be

**CoffeeScript**

```
class test

    myMethod: () ->
        1
```

**compiled JavaScript** without bracket notation

```js
var test;

test = (function() {
  function test() {}

  test.prototype.myMethod = function() {
    return 1;
  };

  return test;

})();
```

**compiled JavaScript** with bracket notation

```js
var test;

test = (function() {
  function test() {}

  test.prototype['myMethod'] = function() {
    return 1;
  };

  return test;

})();
```

Note that in the second output, the method `myMethod()` is assigned using bracket notation.

I need this, so that I can run the output through Google Closure Compiler and still preserve the name of my methods, which requires bracket notation or else the names will get minified as well.

Comment: I dont remember the Google Closure Compiler... you need it for uglification and minification?

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r and some Optimizing of my code, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as I can see on [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/), the best way to accomplish that is:

```
class test
  'method': ->
    console.log 'this is a test method'
```

And u will get this js output:

```
var Test;

Test = (function() {

  function Test() {}

  Test.prototype['method'] = function() {
    return console.log('this is a test method');
  };

  return Test;

})();
```

By the way, I suggest for the minification/uglification to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).